# Roundcube SMTP Error (-1): Connection to server failed

Tags: email, smtp

I am trying to send an email via RoundCube. Recently I manually installed it to a subdomain instead of accessing it via cPanel thus it's way easier on clients. I always get this error when I try to send emails. I can receive emails just fine.

[image]

Comment: Please do not add personal info and contact info.  Any answers should be posted her to help others.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, Finally I've solved it.

**I got the answer**:

1. I opened my `wamp/roundcubemail/config/defaults.inc.php`
2. Modified the following config value: `$config['smtp_port'] = 465;`

it is useful for any one who has installed **roundcube into WampSever in windows** and can not send email.

Comment: Same worked for me on LAMP server too!!!